# Converting JsonResult into a different object in C#

Tags: c#, json, object, jsonresult

So I have an object named `Balance` that contains:

```
public class Balance
{
   string balance1;
   string balance2;
   string currency;
}
```

and I'm trying to parse a `JsonResult` object that is returned by a different function call into an instance of `Balance`.

I've tried using `JsonConvert.Serialize` and `Deseralize<Balance>`, however, the object that I'm trying to parse into is set to null every time (ie `balance1 = null` etc)

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Below is the code I'm trying to parse. Also, I realized that the data access in `JsonResult` is in a value called `Data` and shows up as `Data: { balance1: "800" balance2: "800" currency: "CAD"}`.

```
JsonResult result = admin.GetCompanyBalance(test.CustomerID, test.DevelopmentID); 
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
Balance br = new Balance();
br = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Balance>(json);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to serialize/deserialize and the string you're working with?

Comment: What does `JsonResult` look like? What does `BalanceResult` look like? You only showed us `Balance`.

Comment: What does `GetCompanyBalance` actually look like? Is it actually serializing a `Balance` object? Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your JSON:

```
Data: { balance1: "800" balance2: "800" currency: "CAD"}
```

The object you want appears to be nested inside the `Data` property of a parent object. You could do something like:

```
JObject o = JObject.parse(json);
Balance br = o["Data"].ToObject<Balance>();
```

Answer (score 5):

`JsonResult.Data` is the `Balance` object you are looking for.

```
    JsonResult result = admin.GetCompanyBalance(test.CustomerID, test.DevelopmentID);

    var balance = result.Data as Balance;
```

Or if you want to test the serialization and deserialization you can do

```
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data);   

    var br = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Balance>(json);
```

http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/ASPNET-MVC-Unit-Testing-JsonResult-Returning-Anonymous-Types