# How can I get to the data inside a returned JsonResult in my UnitTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jsonresult

I have a controller method that returns a JsonResult like this:

```
    public ActionResult GetZipByState(string stateId)
    {
        var result =
            _mediator.Send<List<ZipCodeModel>>(new ZipCodeByStateQuery()
            {
                StateId = stateId
            });

        return Json(new { ZipCodes = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then I have this Unit Test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetZipByState_CanGetZipCodesByStateId()
    {
        // Arrange
        _mockMediator.Setup(m => m.Send<List<ZipCodeModel>>(It.Is<ZipCodeByStateQuery>(plist => plist.StateId == "VA")))
           .Returns(new List<ZipCodeModel>()
           {
                new ZipCodeModel(){ ZipCodeId = "7690", ZipCode = "24210" },
                new ZipCodeModel(){ ZipCodeId = "7691", ZipCode = "24211" },
                new ZipCodeModel(){ ZipCodeId = "7692", ZipCode = "24212" }
           });

        // Act
        //var actual = _controller.GetZipByState("VA");
        JsonResult actual = _controller.GetZipByState("VA") as JsonResult;
        List<ZipCodeModel> result = actual.Data as List<ZipCodeModel>;

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal("24211", (dynamic)actual.Data);
    }
```

I can see the data I need to get to in my Json under:

actual.Data.ZipCodes[1] in this screen shot:

[image]

But when I try to put the actual.Data into the result var and then do the assert, it is telling me that result is null.

How are you supposed to do this?

Comment: You cannot simply cast jsonresult data to any type. You need to use json serializer to deserialize it to the target type object

Comment: Looks like it is the same as here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875658/converting-jsonresult-into-a-different-object-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875658/converting-jsonresult-into-a-different-object-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Take a look at this answer I gave to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38446754/5233410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are casting to wrong type.

This line here:
`List<ZipCodeModel> result = actual.Data as List<ZipCodeModel>;` should be changed to

```
var result = actual.Data.GetType()
.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "ZipCodes")
.GetValue(actual.Data) as List<ZipCodeModel>;
```